# How do I update the settings display after using external method to change setting

Tags: java, android, settings

I need to update the Settings display after executing code that changes one of the settings. I can change the preference, but it doesn't update in the display until I leave and come back.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        final Preference btnLexicon = findPreference("lexicon");
        btnLexicon.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                selectLexicon();
                return true;
            }
        });
        btnLexicon.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("lexicon"));
    }
```

The external method operates with an alert dialog and then update the setting accordingly.

```
                SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = settings.edit();
            prefs.putString("lexicon", LexData.getLexName());
            prefs.apply();
```

I've tried the suggestion to use

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

and

```
    @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if ("lexicon".equals(key))
        sharedPreferences.getString("lexicon", LexData.getLexName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to recreate the Settings activity

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if ("lexicon".equals(key)) 
        recreate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually do something with that String you retrieve in the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

```
if ("lexicon".equals(key))
    findPreference(key).setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("lexicon", LexData.getLexName()));
```

Comment: findPreference is deprecated

Comment: You're using the `android.preference` package then, which was deprecated in API 28. You'll need to migrate to appcompat. Either way, the deprecation is irrelevant.